# Upload image without losing quality and small size

Tags: java, android, upload, retrofit

i want to upload images on my host with retrofit , and i use this codes.

target is upload images with low size and original quality , can you help me please ?

ImageChooser:

```
private void imageChooser1() {
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    pickPhoto.putExtra("scaleType", "fitCenter");
    pickPhoto.putExtra("crop", "true");
    pickPhoto.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    pickPhoto.putExtra("aspectY", 1);


    //....snip....
    pickPhoto.putExtra("outputX", 800);
    pickPhoto.putExtra("outputY", 800);
    //....snip....


    pickPhoto.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());


    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, SELECT_PICTURE1);
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // compare the resultCode with the
        // SELECT_PICTURE constant
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE1) {
            // Get the url of the image from data

            Uri selectedImageUri1 = data.getData();

            path1 = FileUtil.getPath(getActivity(), selectedImageUri1);
            if (null != selectedImageUri1) {
                // update the preview image in the layout
                IVPreviewImage1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri1);

            }

        }
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE2) {
            // Get the url of the image from data
            Uri selectedImageUri2 = data.getData();

            path2 = FileUtil.getPath(getActivity(), selectedImageUri2);

            if (null != selectedImageUri2) {
                // update the preview image in the layout
                IVPreviewImage2.setImageURI(selectedImageUri2);

            }
        }if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE3) {
            // Get the url of the image from data
            Uri selectedImageUri3 = data.getData();
            path3= FileUtil.getPath(getActivity(), selectedImageUri3);

            if (null != selectedImageUri3) {
                // update the preview image in the layout
                IVPreviewImage3.setImageURI(selectedImageUri3);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Multipart prepare:

```
  @NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepairFiles(String partName, Uri fileUri){

    File file = new File( fileUri.getPath());


    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    Random rand = new Random();

    int n = rand.nextInt(50000);

    n += 1;

    String picname = ownerid + "___" + n + ".png";
    return  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName,picname, requestBody);
}
```

Upload Function:

```
    private void uploadImage() {


    if (path1 != null && path2 == null && path3 == null) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int n = rand.nextInt(500);

        n += 1;

        String picname = ownerid + "___" + n + ".jpg";

        File file = new File(path1);



        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", picname, requestBody);

        API service = RetrofitBuilder.getClient().create(API.class);
        Call<String> call = service.getAddproduct1(body, name, galleryid, gallname, description, category, price);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressDoalog1.dismiss();
                    Typeface hintTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/samim.ttf");
                    TypefaceSpan typefaceSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan(hintTypeface);

                    SpannableString spannableString1 = new SpannableString("محصول مورد نظر با موفقیت ثبت شد.");
                    spannableString1.setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, spannableString1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), spannableString1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    getDialog().dismiss();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(response.raw().toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("gttt", t.toString());
            }
        });


    }
```

if i remove snip section from imageChooser , uploaded images will have more quality but huge size(4mb,5mb)

i just want to upload images with high quality and small size , thank you.

Comment: Apart from having problems to believe that this 'snipping' for ACTION_VIEW would work its impossible to reduce the resolution of an image and keep the same quality. Whatever you may consider 'same quality'. How far would you go? A thumbnail?

Comment: @blackapps when i remove snip section , the quality incrases but with huge size , what i should to do for reduce size?